# How to View Gradle module dependencies?

Tags: gradle

The following error occurs when gradle builds

```
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

So I found the following documentation:
[image]

[link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors)

But I can't find `AppName > Tasks > android`. I noticed the following tip:

[image]

So I opened the settings and unchecked the `Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync`

[image]

but this still doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already know the answer to this question, when you run the gradle command once, the interface will appear.

```
gradle app:dependencies
```